# Getting the source of an object defined in a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, inspect

Usually, if you want to get the source of an object, you can get it via the `inspect` module:

```
import inspect
inspect.getsource(MyObject)
```

However, in a Jupyter notebook, this doesn't work:

```
import inspect

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, info):
        self.info = info

a = Foo("hi")

inspect.getsource(a)
```

Throws the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-048b6f0c2e9b> in <module>()
      7 a = Foo("hi")
      8 
----> 9 inspect.getsource(a)

/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py in getsource(object)
    963     or code object.  The source code is returned as a single string.  An
    964     OSError is raised if the source code cannot be retrieved."""
--> 965     lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
    966     return ''.join(lines)
    967 

/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py in getsourcelines(object)
    950     raised if the source code cannot be retrieved."""
    951     object = unwrap(object)
--> 952     lines, lnum = findsource(object)
    953 
    954     if ismodule(object):

/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py in findsource(object)
    763     is raised if the source code cannot be retrieved."""
    764 
--> 765     file = getsourcefile(object)
    766     if file:
    767         # Invalidate cache if needed.

/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py in getsourcefile(object)
    679     Return None if no way can be identified to get the source.
    680     """
--> 681     filename = getfile(object)
    682     all_bytecode_suffixes = importlib.machinery.DEBUG_BYTECODE_SUFFIXES[:]
    683     all_bytecode_suffixes += importlib.machinery.OPTIMIZED_BYTECODE_SUFFIXES[:]

/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py in getfile(object)
    661         return object.co_filename
    662     raise TypeError('{!r} is not a module, class, method, '
--> 663                     'function, traceback, frame, or code object'.format(object))
    664 
    665 def getmodulename(path):

TypeError: <__main__.Foo object at 0x7fb9130ee518> is not a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object
```

If I try to find the source of `Foo` (using `inspect.getsource(Foo)`), I get:

`TypeError: <module '__main__'> is a built-in class`

How do I get the source of a class defined in a Jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 8):

I found a "hacky way" to get the source code of a class in a Jupyter Notebook.

Assume in a cell you have:

```py
class MyClass:
    test = 2
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.L = 5
    
    def test(self, x):
        return True
    
    @classmethod
    def forward(cls, x):
        return x
```

Then you can extract the code using:

```py
import inspect
from IPython.core.magics.code import extract_symbols

obj = MyClass
cell_code = "".join(inspect.linecache.getlines(new_getfile(obj)))
class_code = extract_symbols(cell_code, obj.__name__)[0][0]
print(class_code)
```

with `new_getfile` defined from [here](https://gist.github.com/nikitakit/642cb96febdf2f812d0b):

```py
import inspect, sys

def new_getfile(object, _old_getfile=inspect.getfile):
    if not inspect.isclass(object):
        return _old_getfile(object)
    
    # Lookup by parent module (as in current inspect)
    if hasattr(object, '__module__'):
        object_ = sys.modules.get(object.__module__)
        if hasattr(object_, '__file__'):
            return object_.__file__
    
    # If parent module is __main__, lookup by methods (NEW)
    for name, member in inspect.getmembers(object):
        if inspect.isfunction(member) and object.__qualname__ + '.' + member.__name__ == member.__qualname__:
            return inspect.getfile(member)
    else:
        raise TypeError('Source for {!r} not found'.format(object))
inspect.getfile = new_getfile
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I have rewritten a class during the development without committing the first version to git, silly me. Then I needed the source of the first version. Luckily I had the first version class still in a running Jupyter notebook so your code got me the source back. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm having `TypeError: Source for <class '__main__.MyClass'> not found`

Comment: Really cool approach!
It should be noted that this answer only works for classes with methods defined in them. Also - `inspect.getfile = new_getfile` will only work in the current module's context, not in imports (for better or for worse).

Answer (score 1):

Using `inspect.getsource(inspect.getfile)` we can get a segment of code that deals with this:

```
...
if isclass(object):
    if hasattr(object, '__module__'):
        object = sys.modules.get(object.__module__)
        if hasattr(object, '__file__'):
            return object.__file__
    raise TypeError('{!r} is a built-in class'.format(object))
...
```

It seems in ipython or Jupyter notebook, the classes/functions defined or the `__main__` module does not have a `__file__` attribute associated with them so `inspect` wasn't able to retrieve a source file. In this case you can define the classes in a separate `.py` file so `inspect` is able to retrieve the file associated with it.